# Which Venn diagram is appropriate here for statistically independent, uncorrelated and orthogonal random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variable, bivariate

I understand concepts more with visualizations. So I made a Venn diagram for statistically independent, uncorrelated and orthogonal random variables. But I am in a confusion which of the below Venn diagram is correct. Venn diagram-A or Venn diagram-B? Or is there any mistake in the illustration. Also considered here is the case of two random variables.

[image]

Comment: Hint:  $E[XY]=0$ and $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ _both_ will hold if at least one of $X$ and $Y$ has zero mean.  Also, note that statistically independent random variables for which the expectation is _undefined_ or _does not exist_ (e.g. Cauchy random variables) cannot be said to be uncorrelated or orthogonal since it is not possible to talk of expectations at all.

Comment: How are these graphics supposed to work? By definition, a Venn diagram represents sets and their subsets. Which sets are represented here? Ordered pairs $(X,Y)$ of random variables, each of which has a density function and a well-defined expectation, perhaps? What does "$f(xy)$" mean?  How are $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$ related?

Comment: OK, sorry my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize independence of random events $A,B \subset \Omega$ by Venn diagrams. From $P(A)P(B) = P(A\cap B)$ follow the conditions $P(A|B)=P(A)$ and $P(B|A)=P(B)$. The first condition means that the area of A relative to the area of $\Omega$ is the same as the area of $A\cap B$ relatively to the area of $B$.

Now, random variables are basically mappings from subsets of a measurable space $\Omega$ to subsets of a space with known structure, e.g. the real line. Independence of random variables means that all preimages of all (measurable) subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ are independent. That's why Venn diagrams are no longer appropriate, except for Bernoulli random variables.

For correlation and orthogonality, you'll have to take all the real values of a random variable into account. That's why Venn diagrams are no longer instructive at all. Correlation and orthogonality are properties of random variables, independence is a property of their preimages.